# Methods ready and result of Future in Scala cannot be called directly

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I noticed that methods `ready` and `result` of `scala.concurrent.Future` cannot be invoked directly. When I call them in REPL I get an error. Thus I have to call `Await.ready` and `Await.result` instead.

It is Ok but looks a bit awkward. So now I wonder:

- why they cannot be invoked directly;
- why they are exposed as public API in that case.

Answer (score 4):

The reasons are laid out [in official doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html):

> The Future trait implements the Awaitable trait with methods method
>   ready() and result(). These methods cannot be called directly by the
>   clients– they can only be called by the execution context.

That way library designers enforce you to use those methods in proper environment (execution context, **perhaps third party**, or via Awaitable object to denote blocking operations explicitly).

Comment: Ok. Maybe I need an example to understand it ... Anyway, does not it look like a poor library design to expose these methods to end-user ?

Comment: They have to be public to make custom awaitables possible.